# How to create react-native IOS native module for wiredguard app

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, wireguard

I am try to create IOS native module for react-native wireguard app. i have intrgrated wireguard package in to ios app, but unable to config tunnel and connect to VPN

Any one have integrated wireguard with react-native ios native module, there are no resocres avaiable for the wireguard cross-platform appliction,

Comment: You already asked about wireguard in your other question. Please take a [tour] and review [ask] before posting.